# Android 11 cannot delete files in external storage when App is uninstalled and reinstalled

Tags: android

On Android11, files created with APP are stored in external storage. After uninstalling the APP and reinstalling it, the previously created files cannot be deleted again. Calling File.delete and ContentProvider to delete is useless.

Comment: Correct. From Android's standpoint, an uninstalled-and-reinstalled app has no rights to files created by the original installation.

Comment: Is there no way to delete it?

Comment: The user should be able to delete it from outside of your app, such as via a pre-installed file manager app. Outside of that, you would need to use the Storage Access Framework to get access to the file (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`) or a parent directory (`ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`), then use `DocumentFile` to try to delete it.

Comment: Is there any sample code?

Comment: I have a similar issue where I cannot import or overwrite files in public folders after re-install of my app when targeting API 30. Starting an intent to give permission to the file or folder doesn't work. I'm not using DocumentFile for the read/write though.